Yarn PNP module controlled by multiple pnpapi instances
I'm working on a React+vite application that uses yarn pnp. It worked fine, but now I'm having the following issue concerning yarn when I start the application (yarn dev or yarn build).
Error: Unable to locate pnpapi, the module 'C:\Users~\AppData\Local\Yarn\Berry\cache\rollup-npm-4.18.1-ff252ce141-10c0.zip\node_modules\rollup\dist\es\parseAst.js' is controlled by multiple pnpapi instances.
This is usually caused by using the global cache (enableGlobalCache: true)
Controlled by:
C:\dev\Development\ui-app.pnp.cjs
C:\Dev\Development\ui-app.pnp.cjs
From the log, I can see that the same file is controlling the application, but yarn doesn't distinct between lowercase and uppercase: C:\dev & C:\Dev
The folder is actually called "Dev" and not "dev", but yarn pnp is adding these 2 paths automatically, and I don't know how to surpass this issue.
I already did the following:

Reinstalled yarn
Cloned the project into other folder
Removed cache files from (~/AppData/Local/Yarn/Berry/cache)

I'm using Windows, Yarn Berry (4.3.1).
Thanks in advance

Found the issue/solution.
My folder is named "Dev", and I'm using git bash (MINGWG4).

cd Dev -> git bash will be set to /c/Dev
cd dev -> git bash will be set to /c/dev

Both are the same folder, but when running certain commands it may cause some conflict like the one I've got.
Solution:
If you have a similar issue, make sure that the "path" is an exact match of the file system tree (case sensitive).
Valid: cd C:\Dev\Development\ && yarn && yarn dev
Invalid: cd C:\dev\Development\ && yarn && yarn dev
